# Western European Characterset to Turkish in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, plsql

I am having a serious issue with character encoding. To give some background:

1. I have turkish business users who enter some data on Unix screens in Turkish language.
2. My database NLS parameter is set to `AMERICAN`, `WE8ISO8859P1` and Unix `NLS_LANG`  to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1`.
3. Turkey business is able to see all the turkish characters on UNIX screens and TOAD while I'm  not. I can only see them in Western European Character set.

At business end: `ÖZER İNŞAAT TAAHHÜT VE`
At our end : `ÖZER ÝNÞAAT TAAHHÜT VE`

If you notice the turkish characters `İ` and `Ş` are getting converted to ISO 8859-1 character set. However, all the settings(NLS paramaters in db and unix) are same at both end- `ISO8859-1`(Western European)

With some study, I can understand - Turkish machines can display turkish data by doing conversion in real-time(DB NLS settings are overridden by local NLS settings).

Now, I have a interface running in my db- have some PL/SQL scripts(run through shell script) that extracts some data from database and spool them to a .csv file on a unix path. Then that .csv file is transferred to an external system via MFT(Managed File transfer).

The problem is- Exract never conains any turkish character. Every turkish character is getting converted into Western European Characterset and goes like this to the external system which is treated as a case of data conversion/loss and my business is really unhappy.

Could anyone tell me - How could I retain all the turkish characters?

P.S. : External System's characterset could be set to ISP8859-9 charcterset.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are saying that your database character set is ISO-8859-1, i.e.

```
SELECT parameter, value
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

returns a `value` of `WE8ISO8859P1` and you are storing the data in `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, or `VARCHAR2` columns, the problem is that the database character set does not support the full set of Turkish characters.  If a character is not in the [ISO-8859-1 codepage layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout), it cannot be stored properly in database columns governed by the database character set.  If you want to store Turkish data in an ISO-8859-1 database, you could potentially use the [workaround characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Languages_commonly_supported_but_with_incomplete_coverage) instead (i.e. substituting S for Ş).  If you want to support the full range of Turkish characters, however, you would need to move to a character set that supported all those characters-- either ISO-8859-9 or UTF-8 would be relatively common.

Changing the character set of your existing database is a non-trivial undertaking, however.  There is a chapter in the Globalization Support Guide for whatever version of Oracle you are using that covers [character set migration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#g1011430).  If you want to move to a Unicode character set (which is generally the preferred approach rather than sticking with one of the single-byte ISO character sets), you can potentially leverage the [Oracle Database Migration Assistant for Unicode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/dmu/index.html).

At this point, you'll commonly see the objection that at least some applications are seeing the data "correctly" so the database must support the Turkish characters.  The problem is that if you [set up your `NLS_LANG` incorrectly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html#_Toc110410550), it is possible to bypass character set conversion entirely meaning that whatever binary representation a character has on the client gets persisted without modification to the database.  As long as every process that reads the data configures their `NLS_LANG` identically and incorrectly, things may appear to work.  However, you will very quickly find that some other application won't be able to configure their `NLS_LANG` identically incorrectly.  A Java application, for example, will always want to convert the data from the database into a Unicode string internally.  So if you're storing the data incorrectly in the database, as it sounds like you are, there is no way to get those applications to read it correctly.  If you are simply using SQL*Plus in a shell script to generate the file, it is almost certainly possible to get your client configured incorrectly so that the data file appears to be correct.  But it would be a very bad idea to let the existing misconfiguration persist.  You open yourself up to *much* bigger problems in the future (if you're not already there) where different clients insert data in different character sets into the database making it much more difficult to disentangle, when you find that tools like the Oracle export utility have corrupted the data that is exported or when you want to use a tool that can't be configured incorrectly to view the data.  You're much better served getting the problem corrected early.

Comment: Thanks for your expert advice. But I cannot change my db nls_characterset parameter due to some restrictions. Is there any way to send these characters by setting nls_lang or locale in unix shell?  
Because I have already tried setting `NLS_LANG` to `'TURKISH_TURKEY.WE8ISO8859P9'` but it seems to have given a `?`(question mark) instead of turkish characters even the file has been picked by MFT and sent to external system.

Answer (score 2):

Just setting your `NLS_LANG` parameter to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9` is enough for Turkish language.

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you Barbaros Özhan!

Comment: Nice to help @anarkhalilov